# Lotus: I am not able to write Msgbox message to the file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

As all of you know in lotus to print any message we are going to use

```
MsgBox "User has already entered into the application"
```

But this message i have to write it to the txt file so i am using this code on behalf of Msgbox

```
Dim file As Integer
fileN% = Freefile()
Open "D:\sand_p\enter.txt" For Output As fileN%
Print #fileN%, "User has already entered into the application"
Close fileN%
```

and still the code is not writing the message to the file. 
Can anyone help me to correct this above code such that it will append the data if there is anything in text file already and write the message to the file.

Answer (score 2):

From the Domino Designer help the syntax for the  [Open](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_OPEN_STATEMENT.html/) statement is :

> Open  fileName
>
> [ For { Random | Input | Output | Append | Binary } ]
>
> [ Access { Read | Read Write | Write } ]
>
> [{ Shared | Lock Read | Lock Read Write | Lock Write }]
>
> As [#]fileNumber
>
> [ Len =  recLen ]
>
> [Charset = MIMECharsetName]

and specifically, the append command

> Designates sequential output mode, beginning at the current end-of-file. If the mode conflicts with the Access type, LotusScript generates an error. For example, you can't open a file in Append mode with Read access. Unless you use the Seek statement to move to a file position other than the end of the file, the Print # and Write # statements append text to the end of the file

Which means to open a file and append text to the end of it do something like :

> Dim file As Integer
>
> fileN% = Freefile()
>
> Open "D:\sand_p\enter.txt" For **Append** As fileN%
>
> Print #fileN%, "User has already entered into the application"
>
> Close fileN%

Just remember that if this is running on the client, then each client must have a D:\sand_p folder, and that they have write access to it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
Open "D:\sand_p\enter.txt" For Output As #fileN%
```

and as Simon alluded to, if you open For Output, it deletes the existing file and creates a new one.  To append, the syntax is:

```
Open "D:\sand_p\enter.txt" For Append As #fileN%
```